# Powershell Get DataGridView with DataGridViewComboBoxColumn to show default value

Tags: powershell, datagridview, dropdown

I have created this sample code

it is supposed to generate the list of services and populate the list in the grid.
All columns are of dropdown type, with all possible values for this column available for selection

What I can't get to work is to have each row display the default value for it

right now it shows a dropdown with no value selected

```
$DataTable1 = New-Object System.Data.DataTable

$ServiceList = Get-Service
$grid_column_list = $ServiceList[0] | Get-Member |Where-Object {$_.MemberType -eq 'Property'}

$ColumnDropdownDataTableList = 0..(($grid_column_list |measure).Count -1)
$DataGridViewComboBoxColumnList = 0..(($grid_column_list |measure).Count -1)

    ForEach ($grid_column in $grid_column_list)
    {
    [void] $DataTable1.Columns.Add(($grid_column.Name))
    
    $DataGridViewComboBoxColumnList[$grid_column_list.IndexOf($grid_column)] = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
    $DataGridViewComboBoxColumnList[$grid_column_list.IndexOf($grid_column)].Name = $grid_column.Name
    $DataGridViewComboBoxColumnList[$grid_column_list.IndexOf($grid_column)].HeaderText = $grid_column.Name    
    
    $ColumnDropdownDataTableList[$grid_column_list.IndexOf($grid_column)] = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
    [void] $ColumnDropdownDataTableList[$grid_column_list.IndexOf($grid_column)].Columns.Add(($grid_column.Name))
    $DataSourceRows = ($ServiceList.($grid_column.Name) | Sort-Object -Unique)

        ForEach ($DataSourceRow in $DataSourceRows)
        {
        [void] $ColumnDropdownDataTableList[$grid_column_list.IndexOf($grid_column)].Rows.Add($DataSourceRow)
        }

    $DataGridViewComboBoxColumnList[$grid_column_list.IndexOf($grid_column)].DataSource = $ColumnDropdownDataTableList[$grid_column_list.IndexOf($grid_column)] #.($grid_column.Name)
    $DataGridViewComboBoxColumnList[$grid_column_list.IndexOf($grid_column)].ValueMember = $grid_column.Name
    $DataGridViewComboBoxColumnList[$grid_column_list.IndexOf($grid_column)].DisplayMember = $grid_column.Name
    $DataGridViewComboBoxColumnList[$grid_column_list.IndexOf($grid_column)].DataPropertyName = $Service.($grid_column.Name)
    
    
    }

    
    $ServiceList | ForEach-Object {
    [void] $DataTable1.Rows.Add($_.CanPauseAndContinue, $_.CanShutdown, $_.CanStop, $_.Container, $_.DependentServices, $_.DisplayName, $_.MachineName, $_.ServiceHandle, $_.ServiceName, $_.ServicesDependedOn, $_.ServiceType, $_.Site, $_.StartType, $_.Status)
    }


$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,500)
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$Form.Add_Shown({
    $Form.Activate()
    })

# Datagridview
$DGV = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$DGV.Anchor = [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Right -bor [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Bottom -bor [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Left -bor [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Top
$DGV.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(0,0) 
$DGV.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(480,400)
$DGV.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",10,0,3,1)
$DGV.BackgroundColor = "#ffffffff"
$DGV.BorderStyle = "Fixed3D"
$DGV.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = "#ffe6e6e6"
$DGV.AutoSizeColumnsMode = [System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode]::Fill
$DGV.AutoSizeRowsMode = [System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode]::AllCells
$DGV.SelectionMode = [System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode]::FullRowSelect
$DGV.ClipboardCopyMode = "EnableWithoutHeaderText"
$DGV.AllowUserToOrderColumns = $True
$DGV.DataSource = $DataTable1
$DGV.AutoGenerateColumns = $False
$Form.Controls.Add($DGV)


ForEach ($DataGridViewComboBoxColumn in $DataGridViewComboBoxColumnList)
{
$DGV.Columns.AddRange($DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
}


# Button to export data
$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.Anchor = [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Left -bor [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Bottom
$Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,420) 
$Button.Text = "Export"
$Form.Controls.Add($Button)

# Button event handlers
$Button.Add_Click({
    $DataTable1 | Out-GridView # do what you want
    })

# Show form
[void] $Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: So, you do realize that the items on your comboboxes are repeated and the comboboxes are repetead too as services there are right?

Comment: Hi JohnG, can you help me translate that answer into what must be done here in my code?

Comment: I am not that familiar with PowerShell. I will delete my duplicate link. From what I can tell, you need to subscribe to the grids `DefaultValuesNeeded` event. Something like… `$DGV.Add_DefaultValuesNeeded({NewRowValuesNeeded})` Then create the function `NewRowValuesNeeded` where you would set the default values. I am not sure how you would know what any particular “default” value would be given what the code is doing, so I am obviously missing something.